# Git Diff style program C#

Tags: c#, git

I am creating a program similar to the purposes of Git Diff but not able to follow through with some things such as printing which lines in the files are different and higgling the words that are different / missing . I tried something like this , is there a particular thing in the library I could use? (This code snip is only from the MENU Class)

```
 {
        menu menu = new menu();
        DirectoryRead dr = new DirectoryRead();

        //create array allFiles from bin/debug directory contents
        List<string> allFiles = dr.GetFiles();

        //choose two files to check if different. These are the file names.
        string file1 = menu.TextChoose(allFiles, "First File");
        string file2 = menu.TextChoose(allFiles, "Second File");


        //reads the file contents into an object 'readfile'(see Arrayreader constructor and 'readfile' property)
        ArrayReader firstArray = new ArrayReader(file1);
        ArrayReader secondArray = new ArrayReader(file2);


        bool isEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(firstArray.readArray, secondArray.readArray);
        if (isEqual == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{file1} and {file2} are the the same!");
        }
        if (isEqual == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{file1} and {file2} are different!");
            string[] file1F = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(dr, file1));
            string[] file2F = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(dr ,file2));

            for (int i = 1; i < file2F.Length; i++)
            {
                if (file2F[i] != file2F[i])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Line: {0}, Old: {1}, New: {2}", i, file1F[i], file2F[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        menu.endProgram();
    }
}
```

}

Any help appreciated

Comment: Are you using `libgit2`? Or you are trying to reinvent the wheel, i.e. `diff` program or its many flavours?

Comment: @0andriy I am just trying to implement Git Diff like features on a C# Program